# Luke 16:19-31—Is the rich man in Hell or Purgatory?

Tags: catholicism, purgatory

> **Luke 16:19-31 (NASB)**
>
> Now there was a rich man, and he habitually dressed in purple and fine linen, joyously living in splendor every day. And a poor man named Lazarus was laid at his gate, covered with sores, and longing to be fed with the crumbs which were falling from the rich man’s table; besides, even the dogs were coming and licking his sores. Now the poor man died and was carried away by the angels to Abraham’s bosom; and the rich man also died and was buried. In Hades he lifted up his eyes, being in torment, and saw Abraham far away and Lazarus in his bosom. And he cried out and said, ‘Father Abraham, have mercy on me, and send Lazarus so that he may dip the tip of his finger in water and cool off my tongue, for I am in agony in this flame.’ But Abraham said, ‘Child, remember that during your life you received your good things, and likewise Lazarus bad things; but now he is being comforted here, and you are in agony. And besides all this, between us and you there is a great chasm fixed, so that those who wish to come over from here to you will not be able, and that none may cross over from there to us.’ And he said, ‘Then I beg you, father, that you send him to my father’s house—for I have five brothers—in order that he may warn them, so that they will not also come to this place of torment.’ But Abraham said, ‘They have Moses and the Prophets; let them hear them.’ But he said, ‘No, father Abraham, but if someone goes to them from the dead, they will repent!’ But he said to him, ‘If they do not listen to Moses and the Prophets, they will not be persuaded even if someone rises from the dead.’”

**Question:** Could it be that the rich man was in Purgatory, and not Hell?

The rich man had compassion for his brothers. This does not seem likely if he were in Hell. If the rich man in **Luke 16** is in *Hell* (and Lazarus in the bosom of Abraham, waiting for the Christ to release him to Heaven) why would he, the rich man,  try to keep his brothers from going to where he is?

In Hell they want everyone to die, not live, I believe. Could this mean that the rich  man was in Purgatory instead?

Comment: Your last sentence is an unsupported assertion about those in Hell.  If you can support that assertion with a Christian, even Catholic, belief, your question would be far more coherent.  I"ve never heard of tormented souls in hell all wishing everyone to die in Catholic belief. (While my knowledge is not infinite, that sort of belief should have become known over the years ...)

Comment: Mike, this question can be reopened if you specify which church's viewpoint you are interested in.  Beliefs regarding the location of the rich man vary according to different Christian traditions.  Are you interested in the Roman Catholic viewpoint, or some other church's?

Answer (score 1):

It's highly unlikely that the rich man is in Purgatory, as opposed to Hell, for at least a few reasons, as I see it:

**1)** This seems to be a parable about real persons, but related in parabolic form (characters in parables do not usually have names). So that seemingly mutually contradictory aspects therein are simply Jesus including all He needs to teach about the in the one simple story (i.e. *Hebrews 9:27*).

**2)** Jesus famously taught that it is extremely hard for anyone who clings to their riches or possessions to enter heaven (*Lk 18:24-25*). So that using a rich man as an example of someone who 'got off with it'<sup>1</sup> would seem undesirable here.

**3)** "If they do not listen to Moses and the Prophets, they will not [believe]<sup>2</sup> even if someone rises from the dead" describes an unforgiven sin—one of not believing unto salvation. This does not constitute a mere venial sin, but a damnable, that is, mortal one (cf. *Matthew 18:17b*).

**4)** The use of "father" and "son" doesn't necessarily mean amicability, especially because it's a parable, but also as neither does "friend" in Jesus' usage elsewhere.<sup>3</sup>

**5)** "between us and you there is a great chasm fixed" and "saw Abraham far away" would seem to put this place of torment out reach of any hope—"in order that he may warn them, so that they will not also come to this place of torment" seems to be the didactic focus of the parable, and so here Jesus eases out of the parable a little here towards the end and into the conclusion or point He wants to get across (as I find He does with others). In this case, the point He is getting across is the inability to change yours or others' situation once you die.

---

<sup>**Footnotes**</sup>

<sup>1 *Purgatory isn't 'getting off with it' but as far as this rich man being in Purgatory instead of Hell, it would give the same, counterproductive impression here.*</sup>

<sup>2 *πείθω—to be persuaded or conviniced; by implication: believe (root of the word for 'faith' πίστις)*</sup>

<sup>3 *e.g. in Matthew 20:13; 22:12; 26:50 Jesus terms reprobates 'friend.'*</sup>

Comment: Does the church use the words of this parable to prove hell is a literal burning place of torment?

Comment: You can count on one hand the verses of Scripture *dogmatically* interpreted by the Church, but as for this parable, I'm not aware of a treatment of it in the Magisterium. However, the word 'literal' means different things to different people. The Church says not much more than Scripture affirms about Hell—torment, eternal. Much of how that takes shape in reality is speculative. *I* would reserve that Christ *does* say something of the physicality of it, in that He says that body and soul go to Hell just as they will go to heaven in Mt 18:8.

Comment: I don't have the time quite now (sorry) but as for the Church's stance on the 'literalness' of the fire, the [Catholic Encyclopedia](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/07207a.htm) says: "a punishment *symbolically described as a fire* by the Bible."(emphasis mine). Which it simply would not and could not, had the Church defined contrariwise in its dogmatic teaching. Not that the Enc. *itself* is authoritative or dogmatic, strictly speaking. P.S. Christ says that you would rather not exist "not have been born" than endure the pains of Hell, regardless of your view of it. Ouch.

Comment: @Kris The C.Enc. interprets this passage to refer to the hell of the damned, incidentally: " **the abode of the damned..."place of torments" (Luke 16:28)** "

Comment: One day I'd like to read your answer to https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/36920/23657   Thanks again for the extra time these comments took

Answer (score 1):

The Catholic [*Haydock Commentary*](http://haydock1859.tripod.com/id80.html) says this about [St. Luke 16](http://haydock1859.tripod.com/id80.html):26:

> Ver. 26. *Between
>                              us and you is fixed a great chaos,* or gulf; i.e. God's justice has decreed, that the bad should forever be separated from
>                              the good [i.e., hell is eternal]. We may here take notice that the Latin and Greek word, (ver. 22) translated ***hell**,* even in the Protestant
>                              translation, cannot signify only the *grave.* (Witham)

Those in purgatory eventually go to heaven, so the rich man cannot be in purgatory, else he would not "forever be separated from
                           the good."

Comment: you were referring to the rich man in the parable and not Lazarus, right?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are making reference to the parable of Lazarus and the rich man in Luke chapter 16.

The first thing we must remember is that it is a parable, and not an actual incident. Jesus often taught the people in Parables, (or made up stories, to illustrate Heavenly truths); so that they could relate to the world as they knew it.

Far too often we tend to judge the events of the Bible in our modern knowledge, but we need remember, things which are common knowledge to us, were far fetched ideas to people in those days.

Just imagine if Jesus were to say to those people "I'm going to fly to Rome this weekend" none of them would envision an airplane, but it is the first thought we would have today. Their World did not extend beyond their immediate area. Rome consisted of their immediate oppressors. No one of the general public thought of Rome as an actual place it was only the place where their taxes went.

Likewise; Heaven and Hell are abstracts, and Jesus often referred to Heaven as 'the kingdom of Heaven'.

> Matthew 3:2 KJV  And saying, Repent ye: for the kingdom of heaven is at hand.
>
> Matthew 5:10 KJV  Blessed are they which are persecuted for righteousness'. sake: for theirs is the kingdom of heaven.

That would have conjured up images, similar to the Kingdom of David, or of Solomon. While the Kingdom Jesus was referring to is a Spiritual Kingdom.

In this particular parable Jesus could have said that Lazarus went to the Kingdom of Heaven, but it would have conjured up vision of some material Kingdom and not an abstract, in the minds of those people. They were well aware that Abraham was no longer alive to be in some material Kingdom, but he was now in the place people went after death of the physical body, but was now still alive in some place known as the Kingdom of Heaven.

AS far as where the rich man was now Jesus was literally telling the that he was in Hell.

> Luke 16:23 KJV  And in hell he lift up his eyes, being in torments, and seeth Abraham afar off, and Lazarus in his bosom.

Notice that Jesus pointedly stated that the rich man was in Hell and torment. Since Hell was also an abstract, He also had to associate not being in the Kingdom of Heaven with torment and as undesirable.

Often when studying the Bible, I try to place myself in Jesus' place, and think of how hard it would be for me to explain things to the people of that day. I don't even explain things very well to people today let alone a bunch of people to whom most of what I say is like some foreign language to them.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer was written before the edit. It did not take into the consideration that the question asked for a Catholic response. However; I feel the answer is still cogent and have not deleted it for that reason.

Comment: "Notice that Jesus pointedly stated that the rich man was in Hell and torment" Purgatory is considered a part of hades (or the realm of the dead) and involves suffering/torment. So this statement of itself isn't exclusive of Purgatory. Not that I think this parable or story is about Purgatory, but about Hell.

Comment: I appreciate that you recognize this is a parable, but then your answer continues to assume that the parable is describing literal places and actions, not figurative ones. Interpreting it as a parable would mean asking questions like: Who does Lazarus represent? Who does the rich man represent? What does their death represent? What does Hades represent? What does the chasm represent? What does the water represent? Parables don't describe literal events.

Comment: If it is to be taken as literal it should all be taken as literal  if a parable it is all symbolic representation mixing the two is problematic imo .

Comment: I'm not sure the answer is cogent anymore. Catholics do not believe that Heaven and Hell are abstract ideas (though they're not physical places).